# Gradle command line characters limit on windows

Tags: android, windows, command-line, gradle

I encounter a blocking behavior on Windows with Gradle when I build an Android project: Aapt command fails when project folder path is too big.

I'm aware about Windows command line number of characters limit size but is there a workaround to do the Gradle command working, whatever the project path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till the android bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160994 hasn't been fixed, this issue will still occurs.

Workarounds seem to exist:

- Making a hard link in a shorter path may work, as far as gradle
  doesn't resolve the hard link absolute path
- Create a virtual drive
  mapped to the project folder :
  http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html